# The use of "miss" as in "When did you first miss the necklace?"

Tags: word-usage

> **miss** [transitive]   to notice that somebody/something is not where
> they/it should be.
>
> e.g. *When did you first miss the necklace?

From https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/miss_1?q=miss

This definition along with the sample sentence appears near the bottom, so it must mean it is less frequently used. Is this usage still common in modern English? I would rewrite it as:

> When did you first notice the necklace was missing?

Comment: I would say the usage was perfectly normal - especially the second example 'Nobody will miss us'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal, and not uncommon, sense of "miss". The definition page linked to in the question distinguishes between a number of senses of "miss", some of them rather fine distinctions.

The use of "miss" in this way may be somewhat less common than the use of "missing" but neither is at all incorrect.

[This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=miss+%2A_NOUN%2C%2A_NOUN+was+missing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmiss%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmiss%20anything_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20something_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20fire_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20Portman_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20nothing_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20Nugent_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20distance_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20school_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20work_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20methods_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsomething_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bone_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bman_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnothing_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSomething_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binformation_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmoney_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbody_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banything_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchild_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cmiss%20*_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmiss%20anything_NOUN%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bmiss%20something_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20fire_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20Portman_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20nothing_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20Nugent_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20distance_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20school_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20work_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiss%20methods_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsomething_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bone_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bman_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnothing_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSomething_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binformation_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmoney_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbody_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banything_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchild_NOUN%20was%20missing%3B%2Cc0) shows that similar constructions have occurred across time, and are not significantly less common in recent years, indeed if anything they seem to be growing in the Google corpus. (One must be careful in drawing usage conclusions from Ngrams, particularly on es using wildcards as this one does. There are several sources of possible error in Ngram results.)